# what is the use of computeFaceNormals, computeVertexNormals and computeMorphNormals

Tags: three.js

What are the uses of `computeFaceNormals(), computeVertexNormals() and computeMorphNormals()`.

I commented the `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` in an example and the model was appearing like it was given flat shading. when i added `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` the model was appearing like it was given smooth shading. Is this the uses `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.  As the name implies, it computes normals. Look up what vertex and face normals are. The computeVertexNormals-function is quite simple in nature and as you cannot use any parameter for the smoothing (other than "weighted" to give somewhat better visual results), the function will smooth the whole object. Search for this topic on three-js github, I implemented a basic method (not 100% correct) to define the smoothing by angle so for example a 45° threshold will only smooth the vertex normals of 2 adjacent faces if their face-normals do not differ more than 45 degrees. Thus, you can achieve way better smoothing results for anorganic objects.

Concerning the three.js method, computeVertexNormals is just for when you really want to have your whole object smoothed or when your importer does not correctly import vertex normals, you can apply some better shading to your model instead of flat shading which in most cases, looks quite ugly^^